# Scala plugin for play framework 2

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, playframework-2.2

Is there any official documentation how to create play framework 2 plugin in scala, I find [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaPlugins) link but it is not clear for me. I actually need to add to play command like "play migrate", is it possible to do with just sbt? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit uncertain what it is that you are trying to achieve. Maybe you can elaborate a bit ?

The play 2.3.x documentation on plugins, have been improved quite a bit over that of 2.2.x.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaPlugins

Comment: I actually want to add some migrations to my project. For instance you creating class with specific dsl, you declaring sql schema, like in ruby on rails or laravel. Then when you use command like "migrate" or migrate:reset, it is creating or destroying schema. Thanks.

Comment: I personally use Evolutions for exactly that.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Evolutions

Comment: Okay, well I can't comment on that. I have been using Evolutions with slick, for quite some time now. Without any issues.

Another alternative is Flyway, theres a play plugin available too: 
https://github.com/tototoshi/play-flyway

And the flyway page:
http://flywaydb.org/